# Substring method in String class reaches the index it isn't supposed to

Tags: java, string, indexing, substring

I apologize if title is not clear.

Now, in strings index starts at 0. So for instance:

```
Index    0   1   2   3   4
String   H   E   L   L   O
```

In this case, the last index is 4.

If I would try to do something like this:

```
System.out.println("hello".charAt(5));
```

It would throw an 'Index Out Of Bounds Exception', as it should.

However, if I try to run the following code:

```
System.out.println("hello".substring(5));
```

It does run! I wrote similar code, noticed this later and could not figure it out.

Eventually, the question is that how is this possible that we can reach this index we should not? It allows us to write:

```
stringObj.substring(stringObj.length());
```

and it doesn't look very safe as stringObj.length() return us an integer that is one more than what the last index is.

Is it made intentionally and does this have a purpose? If so, what is this purpose and what is the benefit it brings?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is easier to work with `substring` when you think of indexes like this (like letters are **between** indexes)

```
         H E L L O
        0 1 2 3 4 5    <- acceptable range of indexes for "HELLO"
        ^         ^
        |         |
      start      end = length
   (min index) (max index)
```

When you substring from `start` to `end` you get only characters between these indexes.

So in case of `"HELLO".substring(2,4)` you will get part

```
 L L 
2 3 4
```

which returns `"LL"`.

Now in case of `substring(5)` it acts same as `substring(5,length)` which means in this case it is `substring(5,5)`. So since `5` index *exists* in our "model" as acceptable value, and since there are no characters between `5` and `5` we are getting empty string as result.

Similar situation happens in case of `substring(0,0)` `substring(1,1)` and so on as long as indexes are acceptable by our model.

`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` happens only when we try to access indexes which are not acceptable, which means:

- negative ones: `-1`, `-2`, ...
- greater than `length`. Here: `6` `7`, ...

Answer (score 3):

> It would not compile due to 'Index Out Of Bounds Exception',

It does compile. You get a runtime Exception when you try to execute the code.

```
System.out.println("hello".substring(5));
```

> Eventually, the question is that how is this possible that we can reach this index we should not?

Read the API for the `substring(...)` method. It explains how the method works and what the parameter means.

In this case it returns an empty String.

Comment: We won't get exception on "hello".substring(5) But API explains we get "emptiness".substring(9) returns "" (an empty string) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)

Comment: Yes, I checked the documentation, too. But I don't understand that it says beginIndex is inclusive. How did they implement such a method?

Comment: `it says beginIndex is inclusive` - of course it is inclusive. How would you get the first character which is index 0? Would you specify -1? That doesn't make sense. It is also easy to use the substring() method in combination with the indexof() method. You use indexof() to get an index and the substring() to get all the characters from the index.

Comment: I understand that it should be inclusive but I still don't get why it doesn't throw an exception when you try str.substring(str.length());

Comment: `I still don't get why it doesn't throw an exception`  The API specifically states it will return an empty String. The API specifically states it will throw an Exception if the index is greater than the length. So the behaviour is well documented. Personally, I can't think of a situation why I would want to use substring to return an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the substring method at Java String API
(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int))

A String ".length()" method will return the number of characters in the string.

if you count "HELLO" from 0->4, it will still amount to 5 characters (the length), which is the number returned when you call "Hello".length().

If you want to access the last character of a String, use (Stringobj.length()-1); Accessing the last element of a String or Array through utilizing its .length() or .size() method calls is standardized across Java.

Answer (score 0):

In this case details of implementation of methods charAt and substring are helpful to know.

charAt as described in [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_charat.htm) can be described as method that:

> returns the character located at the String's specified index. The string indexes start from zero.

That is why calling:

```
System.out.println("hello".charAt(5));
```

gives

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
String index out of range: 5
```

**Because maximum index is, as you perfectly described, only 4.**

`substring` is described in java documentation and explains your exact situation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) in the "Examples" section which states that  :

> "emptiness".substring(9) returns "" (an empty string)

For additional reference, here is the source code for [java's `substring(int index)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.substring%28int%29) implementation, where you can see that it uses java's `substring(int beginInndex, int endIndex)` method.