# Java String index out of bounds confusion

Tags: java, arrays, string, indexoutofboundsexception

Suppose I have a

```
String temp = "abcd";

System.out.println(temp.substring(0,4)); // out of bound, no error
System.out.println(temp.substring(0,5)); // out of bound, error
```

Why?

Comment: the second parameter is the endindex but the last index is 3

Comment: Not necessary duplicate, but this may interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33600969/1393766

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Javadocs for this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) state:

> The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1.
>
> **Throws:**
>
> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

An end index of `length` is ok, but `length + 1` is not.

Comment: If I type System.out.println(temp.substring(4, 4)); why -1 not showing up?

Comment: @KKKK Why would `-1` show up?  That should print an empty string, which won't be visible.

Answer (score 1):

According to [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29):

`public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`

> The substring begins at the specified `beginIndex` and extends to the character at index `endIndex - 1`.
>
> `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the `beginIndex` is negative, or `endIndex` is larger than the length of this String object, or `beginIndex` is larger than `endIndex`.

Since `System.out.println(temp.substring(0,5));` where 5 > length of string (`abcd`), hence the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Because the substring ends at endIndex-1.

Answer (score 0):

The substring(0,4) does not consider 0 to 4. It considers 0 to 3. The 2nd index is always subtracted by 1. In your second case temp[4] is out of bounds.