# Why does the java substring method work like this?

Tags: java, string

This probably has a very obvious answer, but I just started learning Java and discovered this.

Say we have

```
String x = "apple";
```

Why is it that `x.substring(5)` returns `""`, an empty string while `x.substring(6)` throws an `IndexOutOfBounds` exception? Is there some kind of empty string that can be referenced appended to every string? Just not sure how it works.

Thanks!

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568222/array-slicing-in-ruby-looking-for-explanation-for-illogical-behaviour-taken-fr/3568281#3568281) for Ruby - the reasoning is identical.

Comment: Because that's the way they designed it.

Comment: This should help to understand idea of substring better: [Substring Method In String Class Reaches The Index It Isn't Supposed To](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33600767/substring-method-in-string-class-reaches-the-index-it-isnt-supposed-to)

Comment: Thank  you! I understand now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java substring accepts values `0` through `variable.length` (inclusive). The reason it works like this seems to be to make the resulting string have a length of `endIndex-beginIndex`.

I choose to think of the number given referring not to the location of a character, but to the location of the point between to characters.  For example:

```
0 :a: 1 :p: 2 :p: 3 :l: 4 :e: 5
```

`5` returns an empty string because there are no characters after.

`6` throws an Exception because there is no sixth location.

Comment: Wow nice and clear explanation thank you so much! Yeah, I thought it directly referred to the index of the character. That's interesting! The charAt() method does refer directly to indices though, right?

Comment: Yes, the charAt() method refers to the indices of the characters themselves.

Answer (score 4):

Javadoc says for `public String substring(int beginIndex)`:
"Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is endIndex-beginIndex."

The length of "apple" is 5, so the length of `x.substring(5)` is 5 - 5 == 0.

On the other hand the api doc says that if
"... endIndex is larger than the length of this String object ..." the exception you experienced is thrown. For `x.substring(6)` your endIndex is 6 while the length of the String object is 5.

You are asking "Is there some kind of empty string that can be referenced appended to every string?". I would say yes, that's true in some way: the empty string is 'contained' at any position of any string, and it can be appended to any string without changing it. But I'm not sure if this way of viewing it helps...

Comment: Yeah that kind of makes sense. So for x.substring(5), endIndex == beginIndex, but endIndex cannot exceed the string length so x.substring(6) throws the exception. Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This is the source of substring

```
public String substring(int beginIndex) {
    if (beginIndex < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
    }
    int subLen = value.length - beginIndex;    // if less than 0, throw Exception   
                            //the value.length is your String.length 
    if (subLen < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(subLen);
    }
    return (beginIndex == 0) ? this : new String(value, beginIndex, subLen);
}
```

and when your beginIndex is biger then the value.length(String.length) this will be an Exception

Comment: the value.length is your String.length

Comment: The question is 'why', not 'how'.

Comment: @EJP My English is so bad sorry