# java substring not working as expected

Tags: java, string, substring

I'm trying to use substring function in java, but it keeps throwing an error, I want to know why ? the code seems to be good logically speaking but why it is throwing this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
```

What I've read in the documentation substring takes 2 parameter

```
substring(whereIwantToStart,howManyCharactersToshow)
```

below is my code

```
    String test = "160994";
    System.out.println(test.substring(2,1)); //output should be 09 why error?
```

Can someone explain me what is wrong ? please I need explanation. Thanks :)

Comment: Hint: all Java library classes and methods are documented extremely well. Instead of just invoking a method, you should always always always first read that documentation. There is no point in calling methods without knowing what their parameters mean.

Comment: Example from the documentation: "hamburger".substring(4, 8) returns "urge"

 "smiles".substring(1, 5) returns "mile"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: substring index range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570037/java-substring-index-range)

Comment: Could you provide the document which said " substring takes 2 parameter substring(whereIwantToStart,howManyCharactersToshow) "?

Comment: This should help you work with substring indexes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33600969

Comment: You have to read the documentation carefully, but don't get frustrated, the practice make the master. A little tip: If you are using eclipse, you could press CTRL+space just before "test." to show content assist which provide context, documentation and completion alternatives. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

See the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)):

> public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
>
> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and
> extends to the character at index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the
> substring is endIndex-beginIndex.

You need `"160994".substring(2, 4)` to get `09`.

Answer (score 1):

End index should be greater than the Start Index. To get output as '09', you should provide the end index as 4 `test.substring(2,4);`

> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The
>   substring begins at the specified `beginIndex` and extends
>   to the character at index `endIndex - 1`.
>
> Thus the length of the substring is `endIndex-beginIndex`.

The `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` will throw in below cases

1. beginIndex < 0
2. endIndex > value.length
3. endIndex - beginIndex < 0

Answer (score 1):

For your required output use-

```
System.out.println(test.substring(2,4));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the format for the substring in java

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

you are specifying start from index 2 and end at index 1 , that's why it's throwing an exception index out of range.

To get the output as 09 you need

```
 System.out.println(test.substring(2,4));
```

Appendix - Java Docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)

Answer (score 0):

`public String substring(int startIndex, int endIndex)`: This method returns new String object containing the substring of the given string from specified startIndex to endIndex.

Let's understand the startIndex and endIndex by the code given below.

```
String s="hello";  
System.out.println(s.substring(0,2));
```

Output : `he`

Notice :

> endIndex > startIndex

in your case :  change between  1 and 2 place to

```
String test = "160994";
System.out.println(test.substring(2, 4)); //output should be 09
```

Output : `09`

Answer (score 0):

String test = "160994";

System.out.println(test.substring(2,1));

Substring means (beginIndex, endIndex) and endIndex Should be larger than beginIndex.and your value(09) should be stay between beninIndex(which is starting index) and endIndex(Which is last index).

and you have taken endIndex 1 so you are geting the Error because your beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

if you want to get Ans. 09 then you should have to put endIndex 4.

Line will be:-System.out.println(test.substring(2,4));